# Design problems of ActiveRecord for large application

Tags: php, laravel, oop, design-patterns, eloquent

In most of the frameworks you have model classes that represents row in the database.

For example php code:

```
class User extends Model {}
```

I'm giving Laravel eloquent example but this is true for most php frameworks.

Then you add the relationships in the class:

```
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Picture');
}
```

Then you add some methods like this:

```
public function deleteComments()
{
    // delete comments code here
}
```

My first question is: Is this good design architecture because after years when the project becomes large you will have many relationships (pictures, comments, posts, subscriptions, etc connected to the user).
The class could become 10k lines of code or so.

In that case, the class will become very large and hard to maintain.
Also the Single Responsible Principle maybe is violated because you have too many methods in one class.

Also if I want to use the class it in another app I cannot, simply because I'll have to pull also the pictures, comments and etc in the second application(website).

If I make other classes like "`UserPictures`", "`UserPictureDeleter`" the code will get more complicated.

So is this good practice and if not do you have any suggestions on how to make the code not bloated with so many methods but easy to use.
Do you agree that all these methods belong to the `User` class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel and some another framework provide [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) conception in their base classes of model. The main idea of Active Record is a representation of table row as an object that includes data of a row and methods of work with databases.

Using of Active Record pattern is fully justified in small simple applications because this pattern gives an ability to fast develop your application. But if your application has a lot of code and difficult business logic, Active Record will make many problems in the architecture of your application. Active Record can make the following problems:

- violation of the Single Responsibility Principle that makes bloated code. Active Record always violates this principle, because it always has two responsibility: it implements business logic and methods of database work
- violation of low coupling principle (GRASP) that makes code reuse more difficult
- сreation of qualified abstraction is difficult if you use Active Record pattern

The solution to those problems is using of OOP abstractions instead of using of table rows abstractions. For example, you can use [Domain Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) and [Domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). This approach is better than Active Record pattern for large applications.

Unfortunately, those concepts are too large-volume for explanation in this post, but you can read "Domain Driven Design" by Eric Evans. It is a good book about application design.  Also, you can find many articles about those concepts in google. For example [Building a Domain Model](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-domain-model/), [Implementing Domain-Driven Design in PHP](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-domain-driven-design-in-php) (Laravel)

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, but with Domain Model doesn't it mean i will have more code reuse? Instead of Active record "joins" for example i will use custom ones all over the domain models (user, pictures, etc). can you provide very simple way with code (php, java, whatever) just to get the idea. Thank you

Comment: I added a few articles with examples to the post

Comment: I think the active record vs doctrine discussion is just a matter of personal choice. Claiming that Active Record is meant for small/simple apps is just wrong! You would be surprised at the "scale" of companies that use Active Record. Unless you're Facebook or Google, it doesn't even matter. And if you are, well then you're probably going to develop your own framework

Comment: Any choice of patterns or choice of any technologies is always a personal choice. But this fact doesn't deprive problems of Active Record pattern. Size of a company doesn't show situations in which pattern is applied

Comment: So you admit that your comment about ActiveRecord meant for small apps is wrong? The Doctrine pattern also has shortcomings / problems. It's a matter of choice but both have pros and cons. What Doctrine does in thousands of lines of code, ActiveRecord achieves in hundreds.

Comment: There's a reason why popular frameworks like Laravel and Rails adopted ActiveRecord and not Doctrine.

Comment: Where did I admit that my think about ActiveRecord is wrong? You can try to develop a large application with difficult business logic with help Active Record, but you will have many problems with the support of this application.
 
Where did I tell about Doctrine? I told about using DDD and Domain Model, Doctrine is not a pattern, Doctine is one of many ORM.

Comment: Model is not one row from a database, a model doesn't always contain only relationships. A model must contain business logic. If you will try to create Active Record with many relationships and rich business logic you will surprise how many problems with the support for a long time you will have.
Active Record is used for fast development, but it doesn't use to make quality code. It's the advantage of Active Record. Laravel provides not only Active Record in its Eloquent ORM, but you can also use any ORM in Laravel.

Comment: Doctrine is an ORM that implements the DDD pattern. A model should only contain database logic, not business logic. The problems you are stating are occuring because you have added business logic to models, which is a bad practice. You can use any ORM in any framework or develop your own. Laravel and Rails support ActiveRecord out of the box and not Doctrine for a reason.

Comment: Okay, in this case, we have:

1. non-oop objects, which don't work with their states
2. violation of TDA principle
3. violation of Information expert principle (GRASP)
4. still a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle - Active Record is entity and repository in the same time
5. still a violation of low coupling principle (GRASP), all business logic depends on a database structure
6. still dirty abstractions, which show database structure

Comment: @Paras I think you need to do more research on Application Architectures in general, Active Record in particular. I would suggest Martin Fowler's blog or his famous book `Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture`. I would use Active Record, say in simple To-do list app but Todoist like app.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve your model with Interfaces.
If you need one class to inherit a certain behavior common to another, having designed the interface, you need the new class to only implement the interface.

[Interfase based programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface)

[coding to interfase in PHP](https://codeinphp.github.io/post/coding-to-interface/)

Answer (score 1):

> The class could become 10k lines of code or so

Each relationship function is 2-4 lines of code so unless you have 2500-5000 relationships, this class is not going to be 10k lines of code. If you do, you already have bad database design.

> Also the Single Responsible Principle maybe is violated because you
>   have too many methods in one class.

Nowhere does the SRP state that you cant have too many methods in one class. It states that a class should have only a single responsibility/reason to exist.

> Also if I want to use the class it in another app I cannot, simply
>   because I'll have to pull also the pictures, comments and etc in the
>   second application(website).

This class is a Model class. Its responsibility is to represent one database table. If you have the same table structure in other apps, then yes, you should pull in this class and you would need to pull in pictures, comments, etc. as well since you have the same table structure. If not, you shouldn't pull it in. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: Thanks, i'm pointing also other methods belonging in the model not only the relationships. For example: deleteUser(), getFullname(), activateUser(),  and so on.
The class becomes large and hard to support. If I had somehow only the basic functionality for User without relationships and these methods, I can pull this simple class and use it in another app, but that's maybe complicated because you have to think complex structure and even then you cannot thing of all the possibilities.

Comment: I don't think `deleteUser`, `activateUser` should even exist in a class that's not User. If you have a post that's linked to a user and you want to perform an action on the post's user, you would rather do `$post->user->activate()` rather than `$post->activateUser()`. Also, there would be only limited actions per model, not thousands.

Comment: Yeah, this was just an example, the actions are limited but in a large project they could be hundreds. Some of them are hard to tell if they belongs to the User class or not. For example: $user->disablePayments(), $user->blockAccount() and imagine if you have hundreds of similar methods. Some can say they dont belong to the user class, but I would say why not? $user->blockAccount() looks correct to me.

Comment: `blockAccount` seems fine but how many such methods do you have on the model? Don't think they would run in the thousands for a table with a handful of columns.

Comment: These yes, but there are methods that are hard to say if they should be in user model or separate class. $user->sendActivationEmail() for example. I suppose they could be extracted in different classes, but either way it gets complicated. You have one class with 500 methods or you have 100 classes with 5 methods.

Comment: I dunno how you end up with 500 methods in a single model class. Seems unfathomable. Even if you have a large table with 50 columns, 500 methods seems overstreched. Typically even large applications will have lots of tables (meaning lots of classes) but that doesnt mean they have lots of methods in a single class. Perhaps some of those methods apply to multiple models and should be extracted to a trait. Hard to tell whats going on without looking at the class.

Comment: 500t was just an example count, even if they are 20,30 the single responsibility is violated for me. In Laravel for example: you have methods save, get, delete, you have toJson() serializing, you can call events, basically model classes do everyting. I don't know this seems as bad practice for me ?

Comment: How does having get, save, delete, model events, etc. violate single responsibility? The model has the responsibility to interface with the database. All these are related to database queries/events. That's not a violation.

Comment: toJson is not database related, events are not, sendActivationMail is not

Comment: toJson is serialization of class. It can be for any class. Events are not but database / Eloquent events do relate to the database. SendActivationEmail should be part of a trait and not the model. There is no violation of SRP

Comment: User depends on SendActivationEmail so I cannot reuse the model in app where I dont have SendActivationEmail trait or class

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following [talk](https://youtu.be/dfgtKb-VpRk) from Adam Wathan. He addresses an issue in naming, which leads to bloating of classes. If you consider his methodology of naming methods and shifting the responsibilities, you'll end up with smaller classes and easier to read code.

Besides don't let yourself get indoctrinated by some rules and 'laws' that exist in programming. If you need a class that is 10k lines, but it's readable then go for it.